# does matlab function that returns large number of variables take longer to execute

Tags: matlab

I was just curious
If a function needs to return large number of variables does it necessarily take longer to execute? I have a function that calculates values and stores them in arrays. It calculates these values every time it's called and the number of times it is called has not changed. However now that I have added some return values (each one is a large array with around 1500 double elements, the function returns 8~10 such arrays as opposed to just calculating them) the function seems to take longer to execute (checked using tic before the function call and toc after the function call. Does this cause the total execution time to be more?

Comment: You checked it with tic/toc for both cases and the case were you return values takes longer as confirmed by your own experiment. It sounds to me like you have confirmed that it takes longer. At least for your situation. Maybe take a look at the profiler.

Comment: but is it supposed to take longer? It does not calculate any more values, but returns those that it needs to calculate anyway

Comment: @user13267 it could be because the values now need to copied to the parent workspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact it does take longer if you let the function output more arguements. I guess it is related to storing the result.

Here is my testfunction:

```
function [q, w, e, r, t, y, u, i, o, p] = tests

q = rand(100);
w = rand(100);
e = rand(100);
r = rand(100);
t = rand(100);
y = rand(100);
u = rand(100); 
i = rand(100); 
o = rand(100); 
p = rand(100);
```

And these are the setups that I used to test the speed:

```
clear
tic
for i = 1:100
   %q = tests; %Only one output argument
   [q w e r t y u i o p] = tests; %Several output arguments
end
toc
```

The difference is not huge, but I ran it several times and it does appear to be significant here are the results:

```
Only one output argument: 0.1354 average +- 0.0001
Several output arguments: 0.1367 average +- 0.0001
```

So it will take longer, but I doubt whether the difference is ever interesting enough to outweigh other considerations.